# Customized class don't work in custom/modules directory with SuiteCRM 7

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm looking for someone to help me understand why my custom class in the /custom/modules/ folder is not considered by SuiteCRM 7 despite the documentation (very lacking) says that this is the correct way to proceed with the upgrades, while, left in place, it works correctly.

Some idea?

Comment: It would be better if you share the code block and more details on your use case. On the other hand, SuiteCRM 7.*.* perfectly supports custom implementation in the /custom directory (provided you follow their public documentation).